# Will windows 10.1511 eventually get the anniversary update automatically?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

I currently run the Windows 10 professional 1511, which I upgraded to from Windows 7 (the same edition) on July 25th.

I thought it would be a 30 days delay before I get it through the windows update (due to the provided ability to revert to Win7 back).

But now as more than 30 days has passed I still don't get it in the list of updates.

I realise that I may download and install it manually, but the question is whether it would get it automatically eventually or not?

Comment: It hasn't been 30 days.  The update was released on Aug 2nd.  If you want it today use the Upgrade Assistant Tool.  The upgrade process is identical no matter how you update to Version 1607

Comment: @Ramhound oh, so it should be 30 days after the update is released not after the upgrade win7->10 is performed. That's interesting.

Comment: it could be longer then 30 days, a rolling update, can take awhile.  You were not even eligible for the update until 30 days passed since you recently updated to Windows 10.  So after that window expires then your eligible and rolling update is sent to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should get it eventually. I have some machines that have gotten it automatically, and some that haven't. Apparently Microsoft is doing a phased rollout:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/08/02/how-to-get-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/